# Biblatex: Avoid abbreviations for "editor" or "translator" (modifying historian bibstyle)

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to conform to a bibliographic style that is close to "historian", but instead of the usual abbreviations in the bibliography, they want the words spelled out. So instead of this:

> Turner, Nigel. *Syntax*. Ed. by James Hope Moulton. Vol. 3 of *A Grammar of New Testament Greek*. Edinburgh: T. & T. Clark, 1963.

This:

> Turner, Nigel. *Syntax*. **Edited** by James Hope Moulton. **Volume** 3 of *A Grammar of  New Testament Greek*. Edinburgh: T. & T. Clark, 1963.

I have tried the following, but it does not work.

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{%
namedash={---------},%
volumeof={of},
editor={Edited by},
translator={Translated by}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option for not using abbreviations when you load the package:

```
\usepackage[abbreviate=false]{biblatex}
```

Comment: You will find though the word "vol." is still abbreviated in the bibliography, so is edition (to "ed."); " Edited by" is not abbreviated but that was not abbreviated in the first place (with my version of the files).

Comment: No, those things are properly spelled out. Perhaps there is an interaction with my other flags that is making it work, I don't know. My full call is: \usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=historian,backend=biber,isbn=false,language=american,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

Comment: Might be the case, I could not get the line of code working, but if its solves you problem.

Answer (score 3):

The language file `historian.lbx` (which is an alias of `american`, if you use another language you will have to do some language mapping first) contains all the language definitions for `historian`.

`historian` distinguishes between citations in footnotes (where a shorter, abbreviated form is employed) and the bibliography (a more verbose, not abbreviated style), you will find lines like this.

```
byeditor         = {{\ifbibliography{edited by}{ed\adddotspace}}{\relax}},%changed
```

If `byeditor` is printed in the bibliography "edited by" is inserted, in footnote citations just "ed.".

As a matter of fact, my version of the style prints "edited by" (unabbreviated) as you wanted.

For "volume", add this to the preamble

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{%
  volume           = {\ifbibliography{volume}{vol\adddot}},%changed
}
```

As you have not provided a comprehensive list of words you want not abbreviated, I will describe the process you can go through to change it yourself.

Locate `historian.lbx` (via `kpsewhich historian.lbx`) open it, then look for the abbreviated string appearing in your bibliography (maybe you can guess the strings identifier), be aware that dots will probably be transformed to `\addot`, spaces to `\addspace`/`\addabbrvspace` etc. (as we saw above), copy the definition into the preamble as done above, remove the part saying `{\relax}` (including the curly braces!) and change the string to whatever you want.

Another example:
Suppose you want "edition" to display in the bibliography not just "ed.".
Find the `edition` bisbtring in `historian.lbx`; here it is

```
edition          = {{\ifbibliography{ed\adddot}{ed\adddot}}{\relax}},% Changed
```

the changes you will have to apply are

```
edition          = {{\ifbibliography{ed\adddot}{ed\adddot}}{\relax}},% Changed
                                  modify this              |remove |
```

copy it to the preamble and modify it

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{%
  volume           = {\ifbibliography{volume}{vol\adddot}},%changed
  edition          = {\ifbibliography{edition}{ed\adddot}},% Changed
}
```

The MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,american]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=historian,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{%
  volume           = {\ifbibliography{volume}{vol\adddot}},%changed
  edition          = {\ifbibliography{edition}{ed\adddot}},% Changed
}

\begin{document}
Ah\footcite{westfahl:space}
\parencite{coleridge}
\cite{companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields
[image]

Compare the footnote and bibliography entry; in particular "ed. Gary Westfal" vs. "edited by Gary Westfal"

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{dateabbrev=false}
```

or as an option:

```
\usepackage[dateabbrev=false,style=historian]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. The dateabbrev parameter didn't have the desired effect, but it sent me to the right place in the docs, where I found the abbreviate parameter.

Comment: Great, somehow I forgot the question wasn't about dates...